# How is The Transaction processed on the blockchain side in solana?

Tags: solana-program, runtime

I am trying to understand solana code for our project. So when we create an instruction it will be converted into the message([HERE](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/sdk/program/src/message/versions/mod.rs)) . and into a transaction and sent over the chain. Then it will be in a fecth stage, then banks stage etc...

Can anyone give me a rough idea of all these stages, and where all those stages happen in the actual solana code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can check out *The Lifecycle of a Transaction* article by Jito Labs that goes in-depth about the stages a transaction undergoes.

https://www.jito.wtf/blog/solana-validator-101-transaction-processing/